# Looping through a Column in VBA to copy an entire row

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to Loop through a Column K starting at row 14 until the end. I have written the following code, but it stops working at the Range("K14:") line. I tried using Range("K14"& Rows.Count) but that didn't help either.

```
Windows("Price VolatilityDM.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Activate
Dim x As Single
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("K14:")
    If Cell.Value > 0.25 Then
        Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Range("B:K").Copy
        Windows("Tolerance ReportDM.xslm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K17:Q17").Paste
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: `dim lastrow as long
lastrow = cells(rows.count,11).end(xlup).row
For Each Cell In Range("K14:K" & lastrow )`

Comment: OP doesn't have a `lastrow`... yet :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows("Price VolatilityDM.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Activate
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Workheets("Volatility Static Data") ' add a reference to the sheet for simplicity
Dim x As Single
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lastRow 
lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row ' get the last row
For Each Cell In Range("K14:K" & lastRow)
    If Cell.Value > 0.25 Then
        Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Range("B:K").Copy
        Windows("Tolerance ReportDM.xslm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K17:Q17").Paste
    End If
Next Cell
```

You just need to find the end of the `Range` object and make sure you iterate over to that.  See above; if there are any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It stops there because you haven't completed writing the whole range.  `"K14:"` is invalid syntax.  For example, you could do:  `"K14:K" & LastRow`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this to find the end of column K starting at 14:

```
dim end as range
set cell = range("K14")

'go down one cell at a time until you find that
'the next one is empty. This is the end of the column

do while not cell.offset(1,0).value = "" 

    set cell = cell.offset(1,0)
loop
set end = cell
```

and then use `for each cell in range("K14:" & end.address)`

In your code it'd look like this:

```
Windows("Price VolatilityDM.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Activate
Dim x As Single
Dim Cell As Range
dim end as range

set cell = range("K14")
'go down one cell at a time until you find that
'the next one is empty. This is the end of the column

do while not cell.offset(1,0).value = ""   
    set cell = cell.offset(1,0)
loop
set end = cell
For Each Cell In Range("K14:" & end.address)
    If Cell.Value > 0.25 Then
        Sheets("Volatility Static Data").Range("B:K").Copy
        Windows("Tolerance ReportDM.xslm").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K17:Q17").Paste
    End If
Next Cell
```